# Sonarqube service running, but not allowing traffic to the default port 9000

Tags: nginx, sonarqube, systemd, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops

I recently installed sonarqube to include in continous code analysis pipeline for jenkins.
Having installed the sonarqube and started the service with the sonarqube.service systemd file, Sonarqube service starts and is running in the server, however, I cannot access the service from the web browser using the ip:port or the configure reverse proxy url.
I tried to curl the address in the server with localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0 and even hard code the server ip address, all results into connection refused response.

Any help is welcomed at this point. What am I doing wrong or done wrong.

Thank you already.[image: sonarqube service]